# Enable a directory with .htacces

Tags: .htaccess

I have the following .htaccess config:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^model/([^/\.]+)/?$ /model/index.php?u=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^collections/([^/\.]+)/?$ /collections/index.php?c=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^general/([^/\.]+)/?$ /general/index.php?p=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^blog/([^/\.]+)/?$ /blog/index.php?e=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^blog/archive/ /blog/archive/index.php [L,NC,QSA]
```

What I need is just enable http://example.org/blog/archive/ url and now in such directory there is an index.php file.

The problem is that the above rule /blog/ take the action instead of the last one.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Change the order of your rules:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^model/([^/.]+)/?$ /model/index.php?u=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^collections/([^/.]+)/?$ /collections/index.php?c=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^general/([^/.]+)/?$ /general/index.php?p=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^blog/archive/ /blog/archive/index.php [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^blog/([^/.]+)/?$ /blog/index.php?e=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

However if `/blog/archive/` is a real directory then you don't even need any rewrite rule if you add this line on top of your .htaccess:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

This will load `index.php` by default for any directory.

Comment: Hi @anubhava, it does not work. I have tried both ways. It's quite extrange what's happening

Comment: Do you have a .htaccess inside `blog/` directory as well?

Comment: No. In such directory there is no .htaccess file, only in root and /blog/archive/

Comment: If you already have `/blog/archive/.htaccess` then place `DirectoryIndex index.php` at the top of  `/blog/archive/.htaccess` file

Comment: What error are you getting when you enter `http://example.org/blog/archive/` URL in browser? Also can you show your `/blog/archive/.htaccess` content in question

Comment: I do not get any error. It's just that the index.php invoked is the one in /blog/  instead of the index.php in /blog/archive/.  The content in .htaccess within /blog/archive is the line you supplied me..... DirectoryIndex index.php